# Перетаскивание элементов box2d (cocos2d)

Tags: box2d, objective-c, ios, cocos2d

Возможно ли реализовать перетаскивание элементов (боксовских тел) по экрану в `Box2D`? Бокс под `iOS - cocos2d`.

Comment: Под перетаскиванием вы понимаете следование за "пальцем" если это так, то реализовать движение тела по "миру" можно!

Answer (score 2):

Вспомнив немного документацию можно ответить четко,перетаскивание тел возможно в Box2D. Для этого нужно использовать одно из типов соединений(Joints), в вашем случае нужно использовать Mouse Joint в [документации](http://www.box2d.org/manual.pdf) это глава восьмая стоит с ней ознакомится полностью, а про Mouse Joint вы найдете в главе 8.10 если нужен исходный код или или что бы объяснили более подробно то [вот здесь](http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12) есть урок с пояснениями на примере простой игры.

Ну возможен еще такой вариант `bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;` (или в вашем случае уже `static_body`) переименовать `bodyDef.type = b2_kinematicBody;`

Comment: Да паддле там работает как нада. Но мне эти элементы использовать как барьеры об которые будут ударятся элементы. Как сделать элемент неподвижным при ударах об него других элементов? А то там он летает туда сюда)

Comment: Ну к примеру, вы можете тела, которые буду использоваться как барьеры сделать статичными тогда им будет абсолютно пофиг, они буду статичными(т.е. не будут летать по всему экрану) и потом можете их передвигать.

Comment: Делаю статичными и не могу перемещать))

Comment: А известно количество барьеров-элементов?

Comment: Нет. Будет из хмл

Comment: Ну возможен еще такой вариант **bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;**(или в вашем случае уже static_body) переименовать  **bodyDef.type = b2_kinematicBody;**